# Dynamically stored Jagged array in c++ with jagged rows but constant columns

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dynamic

Hello there I have made a Dynamically stored jagged array using pointers with varying column sizes. I was wondering how can i make this a varying row sizes. This is my code:

```
int rows;
    cout << "Enter no of rows of array: ";
    cin >> rows;
    int *numbers = new int[rows]; /// array to store no of columns
    int **array=new int*[rows];   /// jagged array

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

        cout<< "Enter no of col in row"<< i<< ": ";
        cin>> numbers[i];
        array[i]=new int[numbers[i]];
    }`enter code here`

    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){

        for(int j=0; j< numbers[i]; j++){

            cout<<"Rows "<< i<<": Enter value"<< i*numbers[i]+j <<": ";
            cin>> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    cout<< "Showing all the Inputed data in a matrix form"<< endl;
    for(int i=0; i< rows ; i++){

        for(int j=0; j< numbers[i]; j++){
            cout<< array[i][j]<< " ";

        }
        cout<< "\n";
    }
    
    cout<< "Dellocating the array..."<< endl;
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
       delete [] array[i];

    }
    delete [] array;
    cout<< "done!";
```

open to feed-back! Cheers!!

output i get :

```
123
12
1234
```

output i want

```
111
222
3 3
  4
```

Comment: If it's C++, why not use `std::vector`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You seem to have a variable number of rows in the code above.

Comment: Are you trying to make so that while row[0] and row[1] can have length 12 and 20, for example, you also want column[0] and column [1] to have different lengths, say 10 and 14? If so, you need to realize that column 15 *and* row 13 would have holes in them...

Comment: The number of rows and columns are going
to be provided by the user as input. However, all of the rows are not the same size (the array is uneven).
The user will specify how many elements the individual rows will have. 
the code i wrote above will make it so there diffrent column numbers like the arrray will show like this:
i hope i could explain ill try to display the output i want in the question above

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` -- That is the simplest, safest, and foolproof way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you so much @PaulMcKenzie but do you know how can i implement it i honestly dont know what that does !

Comment: What is the input?  You only show the output.  Second, usage of `new[]` and `delete[]` are not necessary in a C++ program.  That's what `std::vector` takes care of.